# Retrieve data from a WebService and fill Standard Page (Lead) fields

Tags: webservices, custom-button, custom-field, standard-objects, parameters

Here's my scenario: 
I need to create a **basic search**, based on the **custom field "ZipCode__c"**.

User types in the zip code and then I have to use a **WebService** to retrieve the address information (non-US), filling some other Lead custom fields.
The WebServices classes were created and everything is working just fine (I've tested it using the Developer Console and using a custom button, hardcoding the parameters), but now I have a few questions:

- How to call this search (webservice) from the Lead Page using the ZipCode field as a parameter?
- Can I place a custom button in front of the ZipCode field?
- Is there a way to call the search method when the field lost focus?

I know how to do it in a Custom VisualForce Page, but not in a Standard Page (Lead). Any ideas?

Thank you for saving some time to give me a help. 
Best Regards,
Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the approach of the solution. Now I'm using an in-line Visualforce Page to do the job:

[How to make an in-line Visualforce Page to be displayed in the NEW LEAD standard page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73096/how-to-make-an-in-line-visualforce-page-to-be-displayed-in-the-new-lead-standard)