# How to make an in-line Visualforce Page to be displayed in the NEW LEAD standard page?

Tags: visualforce, leads, standard-objects, inline-visualforce, page-template

I created a Visualforce Page to search for Addresses based on the CEP (Zip Code in Brazil). Then I created a new section on the Lead template and added the new Visualforce page. Everything is working just fine. However, the in-line Visulforce Page is not being displayed at the NEW LEAD page.

I'm using Lead as the searchCEP page standardController:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="myCustomVFLeadController">
```

Here's the Lead Layout:
[image: Lead Layout]

Here, the Edit Lead Layout:
[image: Edit Lead Layout]

And the new Lead Layout:
[image: New Lead Layout]

So, how to make the Visualforce page to be displayed also in the NEW LEAD standard page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Visualforce pages only appear in detail mode. You'll need to write up an entire Visualforce page if you really need to override the new record page.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, thanks for your answer.

I wonder why Salesforce allows me to change the Edit layout and not the New Lead page layout. That's really weird. 

Well, is there a way to create new Visualforce pages based on the current Lead layouts?

And I know we can manage different layouts for different users. How to control that permissions using an overridden Visualforce Pages?   

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have Visualforce pages on the lead edit page, either. There's an app on the AppExchange that lets your generate Visualforce pages from layouts (it's free?).

Comment: So... let's say I don't want to override the current Lead edit Page.

So, what's the best solution here? I need to use the field CEP (see image above) as a filter to query information consuming data from a Webservice. With the page I created everything is working just fine. I don't want to recreate the New Lead Page and override it. Also, I have at least 5 more templates for the lead page. 

How to use a field to perform this operation and return data from the Webservice into the Lead fields, in both view and edit mode? 

Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record, I had to override the current Lead Page entirely in order to make my customizations work. And it's working like a charm :)